# FIFO, Mplayer and php

Tags: php, fifo, mplayer

How to user fifo files in php?
I want to control mplayer, I know how to pause file [using system("echo pause > /tmp/mplayer.fifo)] but I don`t know how to send command and read output using pure php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Linux named pipe hanging on open() with O\_WRONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099693/c-linux-named-pipe-hanging-on-open-with-o-wronly)

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/fopen , http://php.net/fprintf , http://php.net/fwrite and http://php.net/fclose .

Comment: Stuck where exactly? "After fopen" is as unspecific as you can get.

Comment: @kiler129 See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099693/c-linux-named-pipe-hanging-on-open-with-o-wronly/24099738#24099738