# Named PIPE is stuck on open

Tags: c, ipc, named-pipes

I am trying to implement a `named PIPE IPC` method in which I am sending `float` values (10) each time the `sendToPipe` function is being called. Here is the `sendToPipe` function -

```
int fd;
char *fifoPipe = "/tmp/fifoPipe";

void sendToPipe(paTestData *data){

    int readCount   = 10;
    fd      = open(fifoPipe, O_WRONLY);   // Getting stuck here

    // Reading 10 sample float values from a buffer from readFromCB pointer as the initial address on each call to sendToPipe function.
    while(readCount > 0){

        write(fd, &data->sampleValues[data->readFromCB], sizeof(SAMPLE));  // SAMPLE is of float datatype
        data->readFromCB++;
        readCount--;
    }

    close(fd);

    //  Some code here
}
```

And I have initialized the `named PIPE` in my `main` here :

```
int main(){

    // Some code
    mkfifo(fifoPipe, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);

    // Other code
}
```

I am not getting where am I going wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Also let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: First of all you must check `mkfifo` returned value...

Comment: check `errno` to see what happened: `if (result < 0) {
          perror ("mkfifo");
          exit (2);
      }`. look at [the man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Linux named pipe hanging on open() with O\_WRONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099693/c-linux-named-pipe-hanging-on-open-with-o-wronly)

Comment: Ok so the error was : `FILE_EXIST`. I deleted the pipe and executed again which 0 exit value for `mkfifo`.

Comment: The proposed duplicate gives you all you need. _Write side of pipe is waiting for a reader_

Comment: @LPs I saw this question, but the thing is that the reader has to read all the ten values together. Isn't that possible?

Comment: I'm not getting you, a reader must open the pipe in read mode, then the writer can do its job.

Comment: Ok it's actually I am trying to implement a system in which I am sending/writing 10 sample of float values to a pipe everytime so that the reader which is another thread (that is processing on those ten samples) will be reading them after I have completed writing the 10 samples and the process is repeated infinitely. What can I do here to implement the same?

Comment: To unlock the situation you can easily start the other thread with the reader. After that I'd start thinking to prepare the whole buffer, with 10 values, on sender side and write them in a single shot to the pipe. So the reader will be awakened (in blocking mode) and it can read all values in a single read.

Comment: Take also note the read does not grant to retrieve al chars in a single call, you must checks that the read data is what you expect to be.

Comment: @LPs just one last quick question. The other answer that you suggested says, when the first process executes an `open`, the pipe is created. Any additional `open` request is on the same `pipe` object file in the kernel. To what I understood that for each write, there had to be one reader and that my first `open` should have succeeded, but does not appear in the case.

Comment: If I'm getting you: Once you launch the first time the program, the pipe was created. The program got stuck and you terminate your program, but the pipe was left open, so the next program launched will trigger the FILE_EXIST error.

Comment: Thanks @LPs for all your inputs, I would see to improve it with all that you suggested. Would possibly post the solution here. Please check it if you get time for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing all the commented points:

1. Program is "freezing" because of there is no reader on the other side of pipe.
2. After the first program launch the pipe was created. Next program launches will return `FILE_EXIST` error.
3. To write 10 values in a shot to the pipe, making able the reader to receive all them in a shot, you should prepare a buffer and then open the pipe and write to it (blocking mode). As a side note take care of reader side: read function does not grants to retrieve the whole buffer in a shot, so you must check the returned read data number.

Comment: how to retrieve the full data from the named PIPE while during read?

Comment: read return how many bytes was read, so loop reading until the correct amount is reached.

Comment: if I need process to create pipe and then read from it, it stuck forever, even if after I run another process which tries to write there. Both will stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @LPs for pointing out what was going wrong. My each sample after entering the PIPE was waiting to be read. I however wanted an implementation in which my reader thread could read all the 10 samples in one go. Here is my implementation. -

```
void pipeData(paTestData *data){

    SAMPLE *tempBuff = (SAMPLE*)malloc(sizeof(SAMPLE)*FRAME_SIZE);
    int readCount   = FRAME_SIZE;

    while(readCount > 0){

        tempBuff[FRAME_SIZE - readCount] = data->sampleValues[data->readFromCB];        
        data->readFromCB++;
        readCount--;
    }

    fd = open(fifoPipe, O_WRONLY);

    write(fd, tempBuff, sizeof(tempBuff));
    // Reader thread called here

    close(fd);
}
```