# Error opening named pipe in c using O_WRONLY flag

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

I am trying to opened a named pipe with the following properties/permissions:

```
prw------- 1 myUser    0 FEB 17 20:08 fifoName
```

I need the open to be non-blocking, so the program doesnt hang. I am also required to open the pipe in write-only mode. however, I have been having some issues...

The following works: `int fd = open("fifoName", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);`

The following works: `int fd = open("fifoName", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);`

The following DOES NOT work: `int fd = open("fifoName", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);`, fd gets set to -1.

I need to be able to open the pipe with the O_WRONLY flag set. I am able to open the pipe and write to it with the O_RDWR flag set. So I do not understand why it would not also work for the O_WRONLY flag.

Your help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: What does  `perror` say?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099693/c-linux-named-pipe-hanging-on-open-with-o-wronly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Linux [`fifo(7)` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening for read-only succeeds even if no one has opened on the write side yet and opening for write-only fails with ENXIO (no such device or address) unless the other end has already been opened.

So when you say

```c
int fd = open("fifoName", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

is returning -1, it seems like a safe bet the other end isn't open and `errno` is being set to `ENXIO` (You can use `perror()` or `strerror()` to get a nice human readable error when `open()` and anything else that sets `errno` fails.)

If you can't use `O_RDWR` to open it, you might attempt to open the FIFO in non-blocking mode, and on this error, do something else for a while and try again later, and repeat until it succeeds.